# Geometry Nodes: How can vertices of a specific group be transformed in Blender 3.0?

Tags: mesh, transforms, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

I have some geometry I'm transforming in my Geometry Node setup. But certain vertices need to be moved differently. Unfortunately the Transform node does not have an input socket for Selection, which would allow only specific verts to be shifted while the others remain in place.

Maybe this annotated screenshot can explain it best:

[image]

So since such a socket does not exist, what can we do instead?

There is [an answer addressing how to do it in 2.93](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220005/2952), but the [Attribute Vector Math node is now legacy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_vector_math.html#attribute-vector-math-node), which changes everything.

So if you guys want to mark my question as a duplicate, go ahead - but please only do so after providing an answer to that original question that is viable for Blender 3.0+ ...Or if you want to answer my question *here*, of course that's fine by me too. I just would like to know how to do this in the current version of Blender. Thanks. <sub>(Oh, the awkwardness of solutions quickly becoming obsolete with frequent software changes...)</sub>

Comment: but you can use 'Set Position' node...

Comment: @calambre Heyyyy, thank you for that tip! I searched all the nodes under "Geometry", "Attribute", "Mesh", "Point"... but did not come across "**Set Position**". Go ahead and post that as an answer if you'd like. It completely solved my issue.  :-)

Comment: please don't get me wrong....it is not meant bad, but i think there is no solution in here for that, because it is THE "basic" node which might be the most important and used node at all. Without it you couldn't hardly morph anything in GN. And it is explained in nearly every GN tutorial and it is part of lots of answers here.

Comment: @Chris I see. Well it's fair enough to say I'm a GN n00b (because I am). I haven't followed that many GN tutorials yet. But I would not agree that because that may be considered a "basic" thing (subjective, btw) it does not deserve an answer. There are plenty of much more basic topics being asked about here on BSE that have answers and are helpful to people. A web search for transforming vertex groups led me to that outdated answer, which actually caused me more confusion. So I think an answer would be helpful. In fact... [I just added one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254466/2952).

Comment: Voting to close my own question because I added an answer to the original one...

Comment: If the answer is for a new Blender version - I totally agree - there should be a New answer…or updated answer. Because I also am really confuse with answers of older Blender versions where Blender looked totally different (with my eyes)